# How to iterate over a production in ANTLR

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, rules, production

Lets suppose the following scenarios with 2 ANTLR grammars:

1)

```
expr     : antExp+;
antExpr  : '{' T '}' ;
T        : 'foo';
```

2)

```
expr     : antExpr; 
antExpr  : '{' T* '}' ;
T        : 'bar';
```

In both cases I need to know how to iterate over antExp+ and T*, because I need to generate an ArrayList of each element of them. Of course my grammar is more complex, but I think that this example should explain what I'm needing. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Production rules in ANTLR can have one or more return types which you can reference inside a loop (a `(...)*` or `(...)+`). So, let's say you want to print each of the `T`'s text the `antExp` rule matches. This could be done like this:

```
expr
 : (antExp {System.out.println($antExp.str);} )+
 ;

antExpr returns [String str]
 : '{' T '}' {$str = $T.text;}
 ;

T : 'foo';
```

The same principle holds for example grammar #2:

```
expr     : antExpr; 
antExpr  : '{' (T {System.out.println($T.text);} )* '}' ;
T        : 'bar';
```

#### EDIT

Note that you're not restricted to returning a single reference. Running the parser generated from:

```
grammar T;  

parse
 : ids {System.out.println($ids.firstId + "\n" + $ids.allIds);}
 ;

ids returns [String firstId, List<String> allIds]
@init{$allIds = new ArrayList<String>();}
@after{$firstId = $allIds.get(0);}
 : (ID {$allIds.add($ID.text);})+
 ;

ID    : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
SPACE : ' ' {skip();};
```

on the input `"aaa bbb ccc"` would print the following:

```
aaa
[aaa, bbb, ccc]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Bart! I didn't know that i could do this.

Comment: Note that you can create your ArrayList in an @init in the rule, and can return it from the rule with "expr returns [ List<MyType> value ].